# How do you write a custom renderer for a Xamarin Switch targeting UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I have a simple Switch control in a Xamarin Forms project. I have read enough to know I need a Custom Renderer for UWP, so I can change the text from On/Off to Taxable/Non-Taxable. Found lots of Android examples but I can't find one for UWP. Would someone be kind and write a quick renderer for UWP and paste it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example at the following [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/81366/how-to-change-switch-display-text-which-next-to-the-toggle).

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Switch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]

namespace MyProject.UWP
{
    internal class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
                return;

            Control.OnContent = "Non-Taxable";
            Control.OffContent = "Taxable";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark your solution as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!